# error method must have an return type

Tags: c#, .net

This is my class  file I am getting an error  as  "**method must have an return type**"

```
public class Users 
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}
public class UsersList : List<Users>
{
  public UsersList 
 {
   this.Add(new Users() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Lock"}); 
   this.Add(new Users() { FirstName = "James", LastName = "Soyer"}); 
   this.Add(new Users() { FirstName = "Jack", LastName = "Sephered"}); 
 }
}
```

I am trying to Binding to a Static Resource of a Collection of Custom Instances

Answer (score 4):

...

```
public UsersList()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: You need parentheses to declare a parameter-less constructor in your class